# Shopify App: Any event for detecting change of theme or make theme sections persist even after theme changes?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I've created a shopify app which adds a new theme section to active theme when it is installed. Now I am concerned that if the shopify store user changed their store's theme then my theme section changes will get removed.
Is there a way to persist my theme section changes. If not, can I listen to an event/webhook from shopify which will inform me of the change in theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There are webhooks for `themes/update` and `themes/publish`](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook). You might try monitoring for publish events with `theme_id` or `name` properties that don't match your expected theme and issue warning notifications about those section data going away.

This is an example response from the docs:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "Comfort",
  "created_at": "2021-04-01T14:58:14-04:00",
  "updated_at": "2021-04-01T14:58:14-04:00",
  "role": "main",
  "theme_store_id": 1234,
  "previewable": true,
  "processing": false
}
```

Comment: According to the docs at https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-04/resources/webhook about this webhook: "Occurs whenever a theme is updated. Does not occur when theme files are updated."
No idea what this even means. But indeed the webhook seems to never fire when editing a theme. Seems to be a dummy without any function. Typical of Shopify with their incomplete and unexplained APIs, leaving issues unresolved for years: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/webhook-theme-update-doesn-t-fire-on-theme-edit/td-p/392790

Comment: Hmm. I can't get at docs for older API versions to verify whether or not it said that at the time I submitted my answer, but all the same, I think if `theme/update` were only to refer to something like "the theme's config was edited on the web admin by the user" (as distinct from the files being modified in the same or other ways) then the webhook is still applicable to the Q being asked

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, if I knew anything outside the theme files which could be updated. What do you mean with the theme's config? I know the config in config/settings_data.json and the config schema in config/settings_schema.json, as well as the template files under /templates. I'm just wondering where else one could update configuration that would trigger this webhook. Editing these files (directly or through theme editor) does not. So what other possible config update are you referring to?

Comment: Ah, no, that's what I meant... Yikes. Could it be that the update refers only to something on the theme object itself? Like... it's `name` property or something?

Comment: Yeah, probably whatever one can change via Admin API on the theme object. Haven't tried, because there's nothing useful for me in there to change.